# Saving custom fields data as right serialized array format in wp_postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce, product

I am working on wordpress with woocommerce and using [WCK plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/) for custom fields. I am creating products programatically.

I need to save custom fields data as array in database progrmatically. But it is not saving correctly and not showing the custom field values in backend for products. I am using this code.

```
 $data= array(
    'alternative-product-names' => $alternative_pname,
    'manufacturers-part-number' => $manufature_park_number,
    'currently-packaged'=> $currently_packaged,
    'other-package-options' => $other_pkg_opt,
    'inner-pack-qty' => $inner_pack_qty,
    'inner-pack-dimensions' => $inner_pck_dimension,
    'packaging-picture'=>''
    );

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'productextrainfo1234', $data );
```

I need to save data in this format:

> a:1:{i:0;a:15:{s:25:"alternative-product-names";s:4:"fgfg";s:25:"manufacturers-part-number";s:4:"gffg";s:18:"currently-packaged";s:4:"fgfg";s:21:"other-package-options";s:4:"fgfg";s:14:"inner-pack-qty";s:4:"fggf";s:21:"inner-pack-dimensions";s:17:"packaging-picture";s:3:"561";}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing your code:

> First, as you have **7 lines of key/values** in your array, so your serialized string **can't begin with `a:1:{i:0;a:15:{ …`** but instead with **`a:1:{i:0;a:7:{ …`**.
>
> Second, You need to embed your array in an empty array to get the correct format like you want:
> **`a:1:{i:0;a:7:{ … }};`**.

So your code will have to be like this:

```
$data= array( 
    array(
        'alternative-product-names' => $alternative_pname,
        'manufacturers-part-number' => $manufature_park_number,
        'currently-packaged'        => $currently_packaged,
        'other-package-options'     => $other_pkg_opt,
        'inner-pack-qty'            => $inner_pack_qty,
        'inner-pack-dimensions'     => $inner_pck_dimension,
        'packaging-picture'         => ''
    )
);

update_post_meta( $product_id, 'productextrainfo1234', $data );
```

This way you will get this serialized data value in your database:

> a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:25:"alternative-product-names";N;s:25:"manufacturers-part-number";N;s:18:"currently-packaged";N;s:21:"other-package-options";N;s:14:"inner-pack-qty";N;s:21:"inner-pack-dimensions";N;s:17:"packaging-picture";s:0:"";}}

Instead of:

> a:7:{s:25:"alternative-product-names";N;s:25:"manufacturers-part-number";N;s:18:"currently-packaged";N;s:21:"other-package-options";N;s:14:"inner-pack-qty";N;s:21:"inner-pack-dimensions";N;s:17:"packaging-picture";s:0:"";}

Comment: Thanks a lot.you saved my lot of time.

Comment: I am getting same problem when saving products attribute.Can you please help?

Comment: You may ask another similar question providing the code you are using and the needed output format… I only can help on delimited case. So more information you give, better is the help…